# How do i make an html document with html in it with java code

Tags: java, html

I want to write a java program that asks the user for information like name, age , etc. Then take that information and make an HTML document on my computer with the information in it. I don't know where to start with making it a web page. Here is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class WritesHTML{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name:");
    String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter last name:");
    String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter age:");
    String occupation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("occupation:");

    int numAge = Integer.parseInt(age);

    }
}
```

Comment: Let´s start with servlet and jsp

Comment: @DRastislav I think he just wants help with html formatting and basic file writing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how to create and write to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

HTML document contains simple text, it's only difference from a standard text file is in the `.html` extension. What you need to do is piece the information about the user together as a text, either `String`, `StringBuffer`, or anything you can output into a file. The text forms the HTML source code of your new page. Then you need to create a new `File` object and dump the text into the file using a `FileStream`. After you close the stream, the text will be added into your HTML file and that's your document.

I suggest you have a look at some tutorials about [files](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_file_class.htm) and [file streams](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm) for more info about how to piece this together, as it is too much to cover in detail in a single post.

Comment: Far better IMHO to link the official docs on [FileIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)